# Value of an area

Tags: analysis, transformation

I have to calculate the value of an area in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given as $ax < y^2 < bx$, $cy < x^2 < dy$ with $0<a<b$ and $0<c<d$ by using a transformation which turns this area into a rectangle.
But I can't even imagine what this area looks like.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Sorry. Yes of course I mean value of the area. Thanks!

Comment: $ax=y^2$ and $bx=y^2$ are two parabolas with vertex $(0,0)$ and vertical directrix. $cy=x^2$ and $dy=x^2$ are two parabolas with vertex $(0,0)$ and horizontal directrix. Can you draw the region?

Comment: So my area is the area between $x^2$ and $y^2$?

Comment: See how your region looks like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%5E2,+y%3D+2x%5E2,+x%3Dy%5E2,+x%3D2y%5E2

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)=(u^2v,uv^2)$

\begin{array}{ccccc}
  ax<y^2<bx & \implies & au^2v<u^2v^4<bu^2v & \implies & a<v^3<b \\
  cy<x^2<dy & \implies & cuv^2<u^4v^2<duv^2 & \implies & c<u^3<d
\end{array}

\begin{align*}
  \iint_A dx\, dy &=
  \int_{\sqrt[3]{a}}^{\sqrt[3]{b}}
  \int_{\sqrt[3]{c}}^{\sqrt[3]{d}}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    x_u & x_v \\
    y_u & y_v
  \end{vmatrix} du \, dv \\
  &=
  \int_{\sqrt[3]{a}}^{\sqrt[3]{b}}
  \int_{\sqrt[3]{c}}^{\sqrt[3]{d}}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    2uv & u^2 \\
    v^2 & 2uv
  \end{vmatrix} du \, dv \\
  &=
  \int_{\sqrt[3]{a}}^{\sqrt[3]{b}}
  \int_{\sqrt[3]{c}}^{\sqrt[3]{d}}
  3u^2v^2 \, du \, dv \\
  &= \frac{(b-a)(d-c)}{3}
\end{align*}