# Finding the area between 4 curves by changing my basis to create a square and integrating

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The question number $3$ at hand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHsh.jpg

My work on it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjw6L.jpg

I thought I was doing everything right but it seems to be wrong, the final answer should be $$\frac{6}{35}(b^{\frac{7}{6}}-a^{\frac{7}{6}})(d^{\frac{5}{6}}-c^{\frac{5}{6}})$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)=(u^3 v^3,u^2 v^4)$

\begin{array}{ccccc}
  ax^2<y^3<bx^2 & \implies &
  au^6v^6<u^6v^{12}<bu^6v^6 & \implies &
  a<v^6<b \\
  cy^3<x^4<dy^3 & \implies &
  cu^6v^{12}<u^{12}v^{12}<du^6v^{12} & \implies & c<u^6<d
\end{array}

\begin{align*}
  \iint_A dx\, dy &=
  \int_{\sqrt[6]{a}}^{\sqrt[6]{b}}
  \int_{\sqrt[6]{c}}^{\sqrt[6]{d}}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    x_u & x_v \\
    y_u & y_v
  \end{vmatrix} du \, dv \\
  &=
  \int_{\sqrt[6]{a}}^{\sqrt[6]{b}}
  \int_{\sqrt[6]{c}}^{\sqrt[6]{d}}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    3u^2v^3 & 3u^3v^2 \\
    2uv^4 & 4u^2v^3
  \end{vmatrix} du \, dv \\
  &=
  \int_{\sqrt[6]{a}}^{\sqrt[6]{b}}
  \int_{\sqrt[6]{c}}^{\sqrt[6]{d}}
  6u^4v^6 \, du \, dv \\
  &= \frac{6}{35}(b^{7/6}-a^{7/6})(d^{5/6}-c^{5/6})
\end{align*}

See also another answer of mine [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043405/value-of-an-area/2043532#2043532).

Comment: How did you go about solving for x,y? And if possible would you be able to look into my work and see where I went wrong? It looked like the algebra and calculus was correct so I'm not sure what my method was missing.

Comment: You've made the following mistakes:

$$(u,v)=\left( \frac{x^4}{\color{red}{y^3}}, \frac{\color{red}{y^3}}{x^2} \right)$$

$$(x,y)=\left( \sqrt{uv},\color{red}{\sqrt[3]{uv^2}} \right)$$

$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_u & x_v \\
  y_u & y_v
\end{pmatrix}=
\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\sqrt{v}}{2\sqrt{u}} & \frac{\sqrt{u}}{2\sqrt{v}} \\
  \frac{\sqrt[3]{v^2}}{3\sqrt[3]{u^2}} & \frac{2\sqrt[3]{u}}{3\sqrt[3]{v}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

By the way, it's inconvenient in switching the image while typing.  So next time, summarize your work using **LaTeX**.